# Removing duplicate rows in Orange

Tags: orange

In Orange, I have a table with row duplicates. How can I simply remove the duplicated rows to keep only one copy of each?

I feel like Orange is great but cannot do simple tasks. I hope I just did not find the right widget.

Answer (score 0):

Alteryx user, I was looking for the Unique or Summarise tools...
My work around is to use the Pivot Table widget
Particularly useful when you want to merge data and overcome the cartesian block of Orange.

Comment: Have you tried unique widget? It seems to be “under construction” but it works. https://orange3.readthedocs.io/projects/orange-visual-programming/en/latest/widgets/data/unique.html